# What is the default index in Cassandra?

Tags: indexing, cassandra, cassandra-sasi-index

I am using cassandra DSE 6.8. I know that there are several indexes used in Cassandra: 2nd index, SASI, SAI, search index, ...

When I create an index on a column:

```
CREATE INDEX status_idx ON table_name (status);
```

What is the name of default index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, since a name has been provided, it will be `status_idx`.  If a name was not provided, one is auto-generated based on the table and column:

```
table_name + _ + column_name + _idx
```

So in this case, it would be:

```
table_name_status_idx
```

**Edit**

Ahh…I get it now.

`CREATE INDEX` creates a secondary index.

`CREATE CUSTOM INDEX` creates a SASI index.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. maybe my question is confuse. My question is about the type of the index: if I dont specify anything in the query to create index, what kind of index will be used (SAI, SAISI, secondary index, search index, ...)

Comment: @David edit made.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one native index in open-source Cassandra, commonly referred to as secondary index. All indexes created with the CQL command `CREATE INDEX` are secondary indexes.

Alternatively, the SSTable-attached secondary index (SASI) is a custom index and therefore needs to be explicitly created with the keyword `CUSTOM` and the custom class `SASIIndex` specified:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX ... USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
```

Note that SASI is considered experimental by the Cassandra community and is disabled by default as I've explained in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/12403/. They are not recommended for use in production.

[DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) which ships with production-certified distributions of Apache Cassandra has an advanced DSE Search feature that allows users to perform complex full-text Solr searches on CQL tables indexed with Lucene. The custom indexes are created with the class `Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex`:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX ... USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex'
```

[Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU), a fully-managed cloud-native Cassandra-as-a-service, includes the new [Storage-Attached Indexing](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/using-storage-attached-indexing-sai.html) (SAI), a globally-distributed index for Cassandra. Indexes are created using the custom class `StorageAttachedIndex`:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX ... USING 'StorageAttachedIndex'
```

The SAI enhancement in not yet available in open-source Cassandra but has been donated by DataStax and is awaiting acceptance by the Cassandra project (see [CEP-7](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/7DZ4CQ), [CASSANDRA-16052](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16052)). Cheers!